# node executable not reflecting code

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to add a publisher to a node that I cloned from Github. When I change the program and rebuild, the compilation process works correctly, but the end executable doesn't follow the code changes. It is very confusing.

Example of code building working:

`geometry_msgs::TwistStamped twist_msg;
twist_msg.twist.angulad.x=4;`

yields error

`error: 'geometry_msgs::TwistStamped...' has no member 'angulad'
...`

So I fix those errors and build with `catkin build my_proj`.

Then I run from a launch file:
e.g.
`<node pkg="my_proj" type="my_node" name="my_node" output="screen">  <remap from="twist_topic" to="space/twist_topic"/> </node>`

In this example, `space/twist_topic` doesn't show up, and neither do other changes. Including publishers that I have commented out will continue to publish. I have tried deleting this project from the `build` and `devel` spaces before building again. I see that when I delete them and try to launch the executable, they will fail to launch, reciting the error that they package/node doesn't exist. I then rebuild them with the new code, and the runtime doesn't reflect the changes that I've made. What's going on here and how do I fix it so that I can publish a new topic? Running ROS Indigo on Linaro Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

Edit: I was able to solve this by removing the `devel/.private/my_proj`, `devel/share/my_proj`, `devel/lib/my_proj`, and `build/my_proj` folders. The issue must have been with the former two folders, as removing just the latter two did not work on prior attempts. Now subsequent builds follow the code changes. Anyone know particularly what happened here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273645/node-executable-not-reflecting-code/) by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-20**:
I posted your results as an answer so that it can be marked resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this by removing the devel/.private/my_proj, devel/share/my_proj, devel/lib/my_proj, and build/my_proj folders. The issue must have been with the former two folders, as removing just the latter two did not work on prior attempts. Now subsequent builds follow the code changes. Anyone know particularly what happened here?

---

Originally posted by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) with karma: 32 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-20**:
You likely had old versions of the executables on your path that you weren't clearing properly. Without your full console output and an example of your workspace it's hard to do more than guess.